# I installed mageplaza smtp extension on m2 EE 2.2.3 (via composer)

Tags: magento2, cache, composer, third-party-module, redis

I followed the directions here and installed via composer.
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

Install via composer (recommend)
Run the following command in Magento 2 root folder:

```
composer require mageplaza/module-smtp
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It installed two folders in /vendor/mageplaza/

module-core and module-smtp

/vendor/mageplaza/module-smtp/composer.json

```
    {
  "name": "mageplaza/module-smtp",
  "description": "SMTP Extension for Magento 2 helps the owner of store simply install SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) server which transmits the messages into codes or numbers",
  "require": {
    "mageplaza/module-core": "^1.3.10"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.1.3",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Mageplaza",
      "email": "support@mageplaza.com",
      "homepage": "https://www.mageplaza.com",
      "role": "Technical Support"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "keywords": [
    "magento 2",
    "magento 2 smtp",
    "magento smtp",
    "mageplaza",
    "smtp",
    "email settings",
    "gmail smtp"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Mageplaza\\Smtp\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

/vendor/mageplaza/module-smtp/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_Smtp
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2017-2018 Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mageplaza_Smtp',
    __DIR__
);
```

/vendor/mageplaza/module-smtp/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_Smtp
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2017-2018 Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mageplaza_Smtp" setup_version="1.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Mageplaza_Core"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

It's not appearing in admin like so: [image]

- bin/magento module:status (it's enabled)
- app/etc/config.php (double checked it's in there marked with 1)
- caching is turned off
- developer mode is turned on
- bin/magento cache:clean
- bin/magento cache:flush
- redis-cli flushall

I can't get this module to show up in admin. Any ideas?

Comment: First check compatibility with your Magento version

Comment: try run:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I have installed Mageplaze  extention as well, but unfortunately It does not shown in the sidebar menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up installing it in the wrong directory. It should of placed it vendor but it placed it in app/code/

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the following to make sure it enables.

**Checklist:**

- Install [Mageplaza_Core](https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core)
- Install correct Magento installation
- Go to correct admin URL
- Flush cache, disable other cache types
- Check it enable: in `app/etc/config.php` and `bin/magento module:status`

The Mageplaza SMTP module menu:
- `Mageplaza > SMTP`
- `Stores > Mageplaza SMTP`

Comment: Sorry @Say Truth, i should of closed this a while ago.

Comment: I still don't have Mageplaza on the sidebar menu, any body know why?